# Database design additional table

Tags: database-design, uml

I have this table called **garments** which is made up of panels, each panel can be coloured in using a set of 26 default colours. The problem is, each garment can be created using a fabric and each fabric allows for 1 or more additional colours.
I have created a draw.io diagram to assist in understanding my issue.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwDqLSd0_WeocU5ndmNqZmc2MTQ/view?usp=sharing

Basically, 
**Garments** have a **fabric** which has a set of **fabricColours**. A **Garment** also has **GarmentColours** which are a collection of **Colours** and **FabricColours** but I am unsure of how to define the relationship.
In my design **GarmentColours** have 2 optional foreign keys: **FabricColourId** and **ColourId**. I think this could be done better, but I am unsure how.

Has anyone come across a similar problem before? If so, how did you solve it?

**Update 1**

Here is a png of the document, just in case you can't open it :)

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to post a png?

Comment: Why doesn't FabricColours reference Colours?

Answer (score 0):

When I studied database design about 30 years ago we used to call that a trapeze. That is one table relates two others. In class design this is an association class. This approach is generally accepted. For performance reasons and by applying some constraints you may hold a limited relation list in e.g. `Garments`. That would be some sort of column like `Colour1`, `Colour2`. As you can see this will limit the number of possible relations drastically.